# Вывод html в alert после отправки формы

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

Есть форма обратной связи, у которой есть кнопка на которую навешано событие отправки письма на почту, после нажатия. Проблема в том, что после заполнения формы появляется всплывающие окно внутри которого вместо строки "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа" появляется весь html код страницы. Сайт написан на wordpress. Подскажите как исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input#name-send, input#tel-send').unbind().blur( function(){

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();

    switch(id)
    {
        // Проверка поля "Имя"
        case 'name-send':
            var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

            if(val.length >= 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val))
            {
                $("#name-send").addClass('not_error');
                $(this).removeClass('error')
            }
            else
            {
                $("#name-send").removeClass('not_error')
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
            break;

           // Проверка tel
        case 'tel-send':
            var rv_tel =  /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3,4}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/;
            console.log(id);
            if(val != '' && rv_tel.test(val))
            {
                $("#tel-send").addClass('not_error');
                $(this).removeClass('error')
            }
            else
            {
                $("#tel-send").removeClass('not_error')
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
           break;   
       } // end switch(...)
     }); // end blur()

    // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
    $('form#feedback-form-send').submit(function(e){

        // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#name-send").val()==="" && $("#tel-send").val()===""){
            $("#name-send,#tel-send").css('border','2px solid red');
        }
        if($("#name-send,#tel-send").hasClass('error')) {
            $("#name-send,#tel-send").css('border','2px solid red');
        }
        else if($("#name-send,#tel-send").hasClass('not_error')) {
            $("#name-send,#tel-send").css('border','2px solid green');
        }
        if($('.not_error').length == 2)
        {  
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller/form.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },

                success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    alert(response);
                }
            }); // end ajax({...})
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
}); // end submit()
}); // end script
```

Файл form.php

```
​<?php
if((isset($_POST['name-send']) && $_POST['name-send']!="") && (isset($_POST['tel-send']) && $_POST['tel-send']!="")){
$name = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name-send']))));
$tel =  trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['tel-send']))));

$to = "mail@mail.ru";
$subject = "От поситителя сайта";
$text =  "Написал(а): $name\n Контактный телефон - $tel\n\n";

$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";

$sending = mail($to, $subject, $text, $header);

if($sending) echo "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа";
}
?>
```

Файл .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress 
<Files beget,info> order allow,deny deny from all </Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если письмо с формы приходит на почту то попробуйте так:

```
success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    alert('Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа');
                }
```

так как "success:" означает действие при удачном аджакс запросе.
и добавь еще строку: "error: function(er){alert(er)}," данная строчка выведет сообщение об ошибке в случае неудачного аджакс запроса. Получится такой такой запрос:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'controller/form.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },

                success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    alert('Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа');
                },
                error: function(er){alert(er)},        
            });
```

также вместо "alert(er)" можно прописать "alert('Произошла ошибка! Письмо не отправлено.')"

Comment: теперь после нажатия на кнопку отправить появляется "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа", но самого письма на почте нету(((

Comment: Значит проблема с обработчиком отправки письма (form.php). Покажи код формы с полями на сайте.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0no41x72/

Comment: <form id="feedback-form-send" method="post" autocomplete="off"> - попробуй так:
<form action="адрес обработчика (form.php) относительно страницы на которой находится форма" id="feedback-form-send" method="post" autocomplete="off">

Comment: и мне кажется что в письмах тебе всегда будет приходить  "Написал(а): $name Контактный телефон - $tel"
в form.php  вместо 
$text =  "Написал(а): $name\n Контактный телефон - $tel\n\n";
пропиши
$text =  "Написал(а): ".$name."\n Контактный телефон - ".$tel."\n\n";

и я надеюсь здесь $to = "mail@mail.ru"; вместо mail@mail.ru прописан твой адрес электронной почты

Comment: не работает (((

Comment: попробуй в аджакс запросе вместо "controller/form.php" прописать полный адрес к файлу "http://site.ru/.../form.php"

Comment: а может быть такое, что результат скрипта за кэшировался и реультат не выводится?

Comment: письмо все равно должно приходить на почту. проверь папку спам и попробуй вместо mail.ru прописать почтовый ящик на gmail.

Comment: да я, что-то не понимаю, я поставил почту на другую но результат тот же

Comment: в form.php попробуй убрать if((isset($_POST['name-send']) && $_POST['name-send']!="") && (isset($_POST['tel-send']) && $_POST['tel-send']!="")){
и в конце
}

Comment: пробовал ещё до того, как сюда написать

Comment: где у тебя находится файл form.php?

Comment: я положил его в папу controller, которая лежит в папке темы

Comment: я не знаком с wordpress но скорее всего адрес к файлу будет wp-content/themes/controller/form.php. Чтобы точно узнать адрес нажмите на файл и посмотрите свойства там будет точный путь к файлу form.php его и нужно вставить в настройки аджакс запроса. Поправите в файле где аджакс запрос
`$.ajax({
                url: 'wp-content/themes/controller/form.php',
                ...   
            });`

Answer (score 3):

В вордпресс для реализации ajax-ответа лучше использовать механизм, предусмотренный для этой задачи самой CMS:

В файле темы `functions.php` определяете функцию обработки ajax-запроса:

```
function myAjaxFunc() {
    /* здесь код для вашей функции*/

    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc');
add_action('wp_ajax_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc');
```

В качестве `url` для ajax-запроса указывается файл, находящийся по адресу `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, в качестве `action` - имя зарегистрированной функции-обработчика `myAjaxFunc`

Answer (score 1):

Оффтоп: правильно пишется "посетитель"

По сути вопроса сложно сказать. Но так как это wordpress то вероятней всего ваш PHP скрипт не отрабатывает, а вместо него запускается сам вордпресс. Было бы полезно увидеть содержимое файла .htaccess

В качестве мер решения вопроса, я бы порекомендовал указать путь до скрипта относительно корня сайта. Т.е.

```
url: '/controller/form.php'
```

А в конец скрипта добавить `exit`

```
if($sending) echo "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа";
exit();
```

И еще небольшой оффтоп: а если вдруг письмо не получится отправить и функция mail вернет false? В этом случае пользователь увидит пустой alert. Что тоже не совсем правильно.

Comment: Содержимое .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files beget,info>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Comment: добавил url: '/controller/form.php' и if($sending) echo "Письмо отправлено. Ждите ответа";
exit(); но результата никакого

Comment: @ChromeChrome значит надо проверять что файл /controller/form.php действительно существует. Складывается такое впечатление что файла нет и вместо него отрабатывает index.php

Comment: файл точно есть, проверил несколько раз